# how to change sharepoint web parts loading order

Tags: web-part, ordering

Can anyone give me advise on how I can change the loading order of SharePoint web parts. I have a CEWP which shall perform calculations based on a SharePoint list below loaded below. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference to hidden CEWP](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62735/reference-to-hidden-cewp)

Answer (score 1):

if they are not visual webparts then you can't control there ordering they will be added sequentially as described in this post,

[Why web parts are loading sequentially?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26487/why-web-parts-are-loading-sequentially)

If they are visual webparts then check this link out,

[How to set visual webparts to load one after - another sharepoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54288/how-to-set-visual-webparts-to-load-one-after-another-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Client Object Model or jQuery to do your calculations, simply wrap your script in `$(document).ready();` to prevent the script from firing until the page has completed loading.